# Link doesn't go to Instagram app

Tags: android, eclipse, instagram

I wanted to have a click to instagram in the application I'm making, the thing is, when I click on it, it goes to the browser, I wanted to go to Instagram natgeotravel application, if there was no Instagram application in my mobile, it goes to the browser

Here is the code

```
  if (uri.contains("https://www.instagram.com/" )) {
            String natgeotravel = "natgeotravel";
            String uri1 = "instagram://Page/" + natgeotravel;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            String natgeotravel= "natgeotravel";
            String uri1 = "https://www.instagram.com/" + natgeotravel;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri1));
            startActivity(i);
        } 
    } 
});
```

I even tried `!` at the beginning of `uri` but still didn't work, it comes with a msg `You must log out in order to reset your password` and `Sorry, we weren't able to load that link`

Help :)